# Singleton implementation and undefined reference to ::GetInstance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, linker

I'm trying to implement the singleton design pattern i found in a book, i'm aware that i might not need to use the singleton here but that aside i've created a GamePropertiesManager and i'm getting the following compilation (or rather, linker?) error: `Main.cpp|| undefined reference to GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance`

I'm trying to use my singleton in my main function like so..

```
#include "GamePropertiesManager.hpp"

..

int main()
{
      GamePropertiesManager::Create();
      GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance()->test();
...
}
```

My GamePropertiesManager is defined like this in a header file:

```
class GamePropertiesManager
{
   public:
      static GamePropertiesManager* GetInstance();
      static void Create();
      static void Destroy();

      void test();


   protected:
      GamePropertiesManager();
      static GamePropertiesManager* _instance;

      enum GameMode{ PLAYERVSPLAYER, PLAYERVSCOM };
      GameMode _gameMode;
      std::string _player1Name, _player2Name;
      int _player1Score, _player2Score;
      std::string _matchSurvivor;
      int _gameSpeed;

};
```

And declared in a separate cpp file:

```
#include "GamePropertiesManager.hpp"
//testic
#include <iostream>

GamePropertiesManager* GamePropertiesManager::_instance = NULL;

void GamePropertiesManager::Create()
{
   if (!_instance) //instance not yet created
      _instance = new GamePropertiesManager();
}

void GamePropertiesManager::Destroy()
{
   delete _instance;
   _instance = 0;
}

GamePropertiesManager::GamePropertiesManager() :
   _gameMode(PLAYERVSCOM), _player1Name("Player 1"), _player2Name("Player 2"),
      _player1Score(0), _player2Score(0), _matchSurvivor("NONE"), _gameSpeed(1)
{

}

void GamePropertiesManager::test()
{
   std::cout << "test success!" << std::endl;
}
```

If someone could look over it an explain what i'm doing wrong i'd appreciate it very much!

Comment: Where is the definition of **static GamePropertiesManager* GetInstance()** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a function `static GamePropertiesManager* GetInstance();` but not defined it. Actually, your `GamePropertiesManager::Create()` is doing most of the work. If I were you, I'd get rid of it and replace it with:

```
GamePropertiesManager* GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance()
{
    if (!_instance) //instance not yet created
        _instance = new GamePropertiesManager();

    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I typically implement singletons. See also [http://www.infernodevelopment.com/singleton-c](http://www.infernodevelopment.com/singleton-c)

Comment: Bear in mind that this method isn't thread-safe; you must make sure you call it at least once before letting multiple threads loose on it. Or better still, don't try to use the Singleton anti-pattern at all; at least in C++, it's always more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Yes, the whole thing is not thread-safe so I didn't want to complicate it, but you're right - and I share your view on the pain that Singletons cause!!

Comment: dohh thank you, i was copying from the book and just got a case of the stupids. great idea above, and thanks @ssell for the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it says on the tin. You have declared the `GetInstance` function and are trying to call it, but you haven't actually defined the implementation for the function.

Answer (score 1):

I see the declaration of GetInstance() but not the definition. Maybe you just forgot to write it?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define GetInstance()!

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the static function GetInstance().

I would get rid of _instance and do it like this:

```
GamePropertiesManager* GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance()
{
    static GamePropertiesManager manager;
    return &manager;
}
```